# Flask gettin 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, api, flask

Im making an Api that get two datas, "id" and "name", but i'm getting `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"` erro in `name = request.json['Name']`

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, Response #import flask library

from checking import checker


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/v1/products", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def getData():
    user_id = request.json['id']
    name = request.json['Name']
    data = {'id' : user_id, 'Name' : name}
    flag =  checker(data)

    if flag == True:
        return 200, 'OK'
    else:
        return 403, 'Forbidden'

    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', debug=True)
```

To send the data for API, i run the follow code:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: v1/products" -d '{'id' : '123', 'Name' : 'mesa'}' http://localhost:5000/v1/products
```

What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What does checker(data) do? You may want to add `flag = False` somewhere before calling this function. 
Make sure that the checker(data) returns something and has a return statement at the end.

Comment: Try change your Content-Type headers to `application/json`.

Comment: Hi Namandeep, thanks for your help. This checker(data) return true or false if the user already exist. The problem is pointing  to 'user_id = request.json['id']'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't with your flask code but with your curl request. You aren't setting the content type and body properly, so there is no json for your API endpoint to process.

You'll want to change the first part of your command to: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

You may also have issues with your quotes in the request body, you'll either need to escape or modify the quotes so they aren't ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me. Hope it does for you:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, Response #import flask library

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/v1/products", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def getData():
    user_id = request.args['id']
    name = request.args['Name']
    data = {'id' : user_id, 'Name' : name}
    print(data)

    if request.args != None:
        print('OK')
    else:
        print('Forbidden')

    return (data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', debug=True)
```